# Getting gulp-file-include and browser-sync to work together

Tags: html, node.js, gulp

I read in a [blog](https://medium.com/objects-in-space/considering-a-static-site-tool-learn-gulp-2fd5f9821fc4) you could use [gulp-file-include](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-file-include) to include .html files, It works but the code below winds up overwriting the include markup in the html...

You might think why don't I have `gulp-file-include` spit out to another destination folder? Reason being is then I can't get browser-sync to refresh the browser after that. Essentially this [link](https://github.com/coderhaoxin/gulp-file-include/tree/master/example) is illustrating my problem...

Looks like there is supposed to be another 'output' folder which will be distilling all the includes into a new `.index.html` file

I know I could just open up the file which is receiving the includes and then browserSync would work, but isn't that an extra step?

Please ask questions as this seems very inceptionesque!

```
gulp.task('fileinclude', function() {
  gulp.src('builds/development/*.html')
  .pipe(fileinclude())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('builds/development/'));
});
```

Comment: I added the `node.js` tag, which seems relevant and probably will give you a bigger swatch of readers.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I hadn't included the `fileinclude` in my `watch` task...

For anyone who wants to check out what I ended up with check out my gist...

https://gist.github.com/antonioOrtiz/2bf2e27b8e0a23115034